# Concerning Random Numbers Generator

Tags: random, numbers

Let's say I want a random number where i did "import java.util.Random;" and

```
int num = generator.nextInt(6) + 1; 
public void display1() {
    System.out.println("Number is: " + num);

}
```

//Edited this is the display code.

```
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Number is: " + num);

}
```

When I run the java program, it will give a random number of course.

But here's the problem:
when I call it from another class, lets say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pList[i].display();

}
```

When I run this code, it will output

```
Number is: 6 //if 6 is the random number.
Number is: 6
Number is: 6
Number is: 6
Number is: 6 //instead of output of 5 different numbers.
```

So my question is, if there is anyway to solve this issue? It should come out with 5 different numbers. Example:

```
Number is: 6 
Number is: 3
Number is: 2
Number is: 5
Number is: 1
```

Comment: http://dilbert.com/fast/2001-10-25/

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/ (actually could sort of answer the question here if we knew how `pList[i]` was initialized)

Comment: What is the type of `pList`? How is it allocated? What is the implementation of `display()`?

Comment: the display() implementation is:

public void display() {
    System.out.println("Number is: " + num);

}

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I don't really understand how your classes are structured but:

After trying to guess it, my best advice is to initialize your generator with a seed: `generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());`, and then assign to num a new random value.

Or use the `setSeed(long seed)` somewhere before you assign a value to `num` with the same parameter as before. That is: `generator.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());`

This way you should get random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly if you don't use the 'display()' method, but the 'nextInt()' method. Try this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
        Random generator = new Random ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(generator.nextInt(6) + 1); 
        }
    }
```

Good luck!

Edit (Now with a function):

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        random (1000);
    }

    private static void random (int n) {
        Random generator = new Random ();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(generator.nextInt(6) + 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Works perfectly, was that so hard? (You might also want to read http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html. All about random numbers.)

Comment: Thanks, but let's say I want to call this method from another class,
So the code that has the random generator is class Random.java. 
For me to call it from another class I would need something like:
Random randomNum = new Random():
for (int i =0; i<5;i++){
randomNum.display();
}

When I do this, it will keep displaying the same number of random number.
Anyway to solve this? thx so much for your help.

Comment: Edited, please mark my answer as the answer if you like it. Thanks!